# Why when I do 4 clusters clustering with K-means, I have only one intertia and not 4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataframe and I did 4 clusters clustering using sklearn KMeans function:

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters=4, init='random', n_init=10, max_iter=10,
                    tol=1e-4, random_state=10, algorithm='full', )  
km.fit(df)
```

So , i have 4 clusters, but when i do this:

```
km.inertia_
```

I get only one value:

```
1732.350
```

However according to definition of inertia, it is a sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center. So there must be 4 inertia values not 1 or am i wrong?

Comment: It is a scalar `inertia_ : float` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: Note, from your definition (emphasis mine): "_sum_ of squared distances of samples to _their_ closest cluster center" so if you take the squared distance of EACH sample to it's closest cluster center, and then sum ALL of them, you arrive at a single number

Comment: @G.Anderson so you mean that its a sum of 4 distances of samples to their closest cluster center?

Comment: @G.Anderson  and can i see separate distances of each cluster?

Comment: 1) yes, exactly. 2)You can get to that information, but you would have to calculate it manually by predicting the cluster each sample belongs to with `km.predict`, then calculate the euclidean distance from each sample to the center of the cluster to which it's assigned (gotten with `km.cluster_centers_`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inertia is used as a criteria to select the best clustarization among several runs. To be able to find the best one, all clusterizations should be ordered in some way. This is done by assigning a single scalar value called inertia to each of them so they can be easily compared to each other. This value is not meant to be used in any other way.

Here is current implementation of calculation of its value in the case the matrix is dense (source code is available [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/_k_means_fast.pyx#L102)):

```
cpdef floating _inertia_dense(
        np.ndarray[floating, ndim=2, mode='c'] X,  # IN
        floating[::1] sample_weight,               # IN
        floating[:, ::1] centers,                  # IN
        int[::1] labels):                          # IN
    """Compute inertia for dense input data
    Sum of squared distance between each sample and its assigned center.
    """
    cdef:
        int n_samples = X.shape[0]
        int n_features = X.shape[1]
        int i, j

        floating sq_dist = 0.0
        floating inertia = 0.0

    for i in range(n_samples):
        j = labels[i]
        sq_dist = _euclidean_dense_dense(&X[i, 0], &centers[j, 0],
                                         n_features, True)
        inertia += sq_dist * sample_weight[i]

    return inertia
```

There is a single loop, which runs through all clusters and accumulates the sum, so it doesn't provide a way to get inertia values for each cluster separately. If you need inertia for each cluster, then you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute `interia` is a number, it's a sum of squared distances of samples to their nearest cluster center.

Comment: While this is technically correct, you've just reposted the definition that OP already included in their question. For a good answer, it would make sense to help clear up the confusion about specifically what that definition means